# Paging not working inside gridview indside update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-paging

I have placed two grid views inside update panel. Both of them allow paging to show the data.

My code of `.aspx` page is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMaster" runat="server" >
     <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="TeamBox">
            <asp:GridView ID="MangersGrid" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="MangersGrid_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Team Managers" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <div class="TeamBox">
            <asp:GridView ID="MembersGrid" AllowPaging="true" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="MembersGrid_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Team Members" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My code for `.cs` is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {   
    DoProcess();
}
void DoProcess() {
    // logic to get data table records one for each.
    MangersGrid.DataSource = dtManagers;
    MangersGrid.DataBind();
    MembersGrid.DataSource = dtNativeMembers;
    MembersGrid.DataBind();
    upMaster.Update();
}
void MangersGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    MangersGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DoProcess();
}
// Members Gridview page index change event
void MembersGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    MembersGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DoProcess();
}
```

The page control shows number of pages but it only renders first page. If I click on next page it does not do anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you call DoProcess() before assigning the page index MembersGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

Comment: Changed the sequence of code in `PageIndexChanging` i.e. DoProcess() is called first. It throws an error 'Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.`. when i click on next page. @Bayeni

Comment: Wrap `DoProcess()` called under `Page_Load` inside `!IsPostBack`.